# Select rows based on closest date while meeting additional criteria in R

Tags: r, function, date, select

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- read.table(text = "OID      Local_date      Dateincide      Join_Count      TARGET_FID      JOIN_FID        indiv_code      indiv_name      sex     month       year        treatment       perturbati      xx      yy      id_treatme      id_treat_1      lion_month      treatment_      OID_hc      DateRecord      Year_1      location        village     Longhomest      Lathomeste      Longitude       Latitude        Animalslos      Specieslos
3   2015-10-25  2008-01-15  1   127415  2   NGAaF1  Ngamo_Urchin    F   10  2015    E   A   547514.43970000000  7883074.46200000000 11  11E NGAaF1_10_2015  11E_NGAaF1_10_2015  3   19-02-08    2008    E   Nganyana    548505  7881998 547800  7883200 4   cattle
3   2016-01-18  2008-01-15  1   128429  2   NGAaF1  Ngamo_Urchin    F   1   2016    E   A   547461.30170000000  7882858.82600000000 11  11E NGAaF1_1_2016   11E_NGAaF1_1_2016   3   19-02-08    2008    E   Nganyana    548505  7881998 547800  7883200 4   cattle
3   2016-02-23  2008-01-15  1   128858  2   NGAaF1  Ngamo_Urchin    F   2   2016    E   A   547395.24460000000  7883056.29100000000 11  11E NGAaF1_2_2016   11E_NGAaF1_2_2016   3   19-02-08    2008    E   Nganyana    548505  7881998 547800  7883200 4   cattle
3   2015-10-25  2008-01-15  1   130659  2   NGAaF1  Ngamo_Urchin    F   10  2015    E   A   547514.43970000000  7883074.46200000000 12  12E NGAaF1_10_2015  12E_NGAaF1_10_2015  3   19-02-08    2008    E   Nganyana    548505  7881998 547800  7883200 4   cattle
3   2016-01-18  2008-01-15  1   131673  2   NGAaF1  Ngamo_Urchin    F   1   2016    E   A   547461.30170000000  7882858.82600000000 12  12E NGAaF1_1_2016   12E_NGAaF1_1_2016   3   19-02-08    2008    E   Nganyana    548505  7881998 547800  7883200 4   cattle
3   2016-02-23  2008-01-15  1   132102  2   NGAaF1  Ngamo_Urchin    F   2   2016    E   A   547395.24460000000  7883056.29100000000 12  12E NGAaF1_2_2016   12E_NGAaF1_2_2016   3   19-02-08    2008    E   Nganyana    548505  7881998 547800  7883200 4   cattle", header = TRUE)
```

Each row is a record with a code `"OID"`, a `"Local_date"`, `"Dateincide"` and other attributes. I have missing data which right now is not coded as NA but left blank. The original data set is large and it has 120,000 rows and 40 columns, which is why I am trying to find an R code that will do the following in the most efficient way:

I want to go through the `OID` values and for all the rows that share the same `OID` to look for the row for which `"Dateincide"` is closest (either before or after) to the `"Local_date"`. Then to write "Keep" for these rows with the closest date in a new column named `"Keep/delete"`.

There is a condition though: There are rows that will have the same OID and will have the same "Local_date", so it seems like in some cases there will be two or more records that are the same match. I want to keep all of these matches not just one, because they represent different records according to the column "id_treat_1".

The output that I want is the following (I have made it short to make it clear but I want to keep all the rest of the columns as well):

```
OID Local_date  Dateincide  keep/delete id_treat_1
3   2015-10-25  2008-01-15  keep        11E
3   2016-01-18  2008-01-15  delete      11E 
3   2016-02-23  2008-01-15  delete      11E 
3   2015-10-25  2008-01-15  keep        12E 
3   2016-01-18  2008-01-15  delete      12E 
3   2016-02-23  2008-01-15  delete      12E 
13  2011-11-08  2008-02-14  keep        7E
```

So there are 2 records with the same OID= 3 that have been labelled "keep" because they have the closest date in "Local_date" to "Dateincide" and they have a different value in the "id_treat_1" column. In the case of the record with OID 13 the row with the closest date was picked and there is only one because there wasn't another match that had a different value in the "id_treat_1" column.

Any help on how to compute this "Keep/delete" column that would allow for multiple matches and how to deal with the missing data will be very much appreciated!

Comment: could you post an example that will take into consideration all of your constrains? i.e. with different IDs and different id_treats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your dates into `POSIXct` so you can subtract them. You can then use `dplyr` to create the keep/delete column.

```
library(dplyr)
data$Local_date <- as.POSIXct(data$Local_date,
                                format='%Y-%m-%d')
data$Dateincide <- as.POSIXct(data$Dateincide,
                                format='%Y-%m-%d')
data %>% 
  group_by(OID) %>% 
   mutate(keep.delete = 
        ifelse(Local_date - Dateincide == min(Local_date - Dateincide), 'keep', 'delete'))

#     OID Local_date Dateincide id_treat_1 keep.delete
#  (int)     (time)     (time)      (dbl)       (chr)
#1     3 2015-10-25 2008-01-15         11        keep
#2     3 2016-01-18 2008-01-15         11      delete
#3     3 2016-02-23 2008-01-15         11      delete
#4     3 2015-10-25 2008-01-15         12        keep
#5     3 2016-01-18 2008-01-15         12      delete
#6     3 2016-02-23 2008-01-15         12      delete
```

Regarding your `id_treat_1` constraint, you can save the above as a new data frame (say `data3`) and then do

```
data3$keep.delete[duplicated(data3)] <- 'delete'
```